# Text search multiple fileds not working in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to search by concatenating these firstName,middleName and lastName fields

Here is my model

```
var lectureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName:{
     type:String,
     require:"First Name can\'t be empty "
   },
 middleName:{
     type:String,
     require:"Middle Name can\'t be empty "

 },  
 lastName:{
     type:String,
     require:"Last Name can\'t be empty ",
  },
 email:{
     type:String,
     require:"Email can\'t be empty "
 }
};
lectureSchema.index({firstName:'text', middleName:'text',lastName:'text'});

mongoose.model('Lecture',lectureSchema);
```

And also here is my Function respond to search API

```
module.exports.findLecture=(req,res)=>{
 var query = req.params.query;
 Lecture.find({
      $text: {
          $search:query
      }
      
  }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (result) {
          res.json(result)
      } else {
          res.send(JSON.stringify({
              error : 'Error'
          }))
      }
  })

}
```

here is the route

```
router.get('/findLecture/:query',checkerUser.findLecture);
```

But, this only seems to fetch documents that match the firstName field. It doesn't match middleName and lastName field.someone please help me.

Comment: I think https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/10/15/mongodb-how-to-filter-by-multiple-fields/ may help

Or you can try using  $concat: ['$firstName', '$middleName', '$lastName']

Comment: just curious to know what is the purpose of searching the name by concatenated string? If you are receiveing the name as full name you can split to grab firstName, lastName, and midlleName and search directly using an and condition in the where clause probably.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented query to solve this,

Please follow the link,

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3GW2FYH95tj

You have to use aggregation queries to achieve your requirement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: {
        $concat: [
          "$firstName",
          "$middleName",
          "$lastName"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      name: {
        $regex: "john1unknown1Doe1"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Replace "john1unknown1Doe1" with your regex value like new Regex(req.query.search).